# How to find different nodes in proximity to each other in OSM?

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

I have been tasked with researching good locations for vending machines.
I have positive factors such as:

- School nearby
- Bus Stop nearby
- Gas station nearby

Then I have some negative factors like:

- fast food joints
- super markets

and others.

I am trying to find a systematic way of identifying good places.

What I really need is to display nodes, which are nearby each other but are not nearby my negative list.

So far I managed to display multiple types of nodes in overpass turbo with the following code:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“amenity=school”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  node["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});
  relation["industrial"="factory"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ZVJ

Bus Stops and Schools are shown, however, factories for some reason are not.
How can I filter from here to, for example only show bus stops and school in close proximity to each other? How do I exclude nodes based on proximity to other nodes?

Are there any other useful methods I should look at to achieve my aim of finding the best places for vending machines? Is there a way to visualize traffic statistics (busy roads) on OSM?

Answer (score 1):

> Bus Stops and Schools are shown, however, factories for some reason are not.

Are there any other useful methods I should look at to achieve my aim of finding the best places for vending machines? Is there a way to visualize traffic statistics (busy roads) on OSM?

You are only searching on `relation` for factories. Some tags are used as `nodes` or `ways`. Here is the description of OSM tag data structures: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements

If you go to each of these  tag pages, you'll see a link to overpass-turbo with all possibilities for that tag:

- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dschool
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:industrial%3Dfactory
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dbus_stop

Here's an updated "full" query, which can be simplified when you find out what kind of objects are returned for each tag: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ZVz

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
   // query part for: “highway=bus_stop”
  node["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
  way["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
  relation["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});

  // query part for: “amenity=school”
  node["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});

  // query part for: “industrial=factory”
  node["industrial"="factory"]({{bbox}});
  way["industrial"="factory"]({{bbox}});
  relation["industrial"="factory"]({{bbox}});

);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

> How can I filter from here to, for example only show bus stops and school in close proximity to each other?

Eventually you'll have to [download bulk files](https://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html) and run [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) and [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) on them. Search this forum or others for steps for this process.

For distance between nodes, instead of actual "distance", you may want to use Routing: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

> How do I exclude nodes based on proximity to other nodes?

Probably this should be its own question, perhaps on https://gis.stackexchange.com

But once you have raw data locally, there are many tools to parse and filter, or write your own, which can use whatever distance/proximity metric you desire. In the end, all the nodes/ways/relations are series of latitude/longitude for which you can apply mathematical operations.

Comment: Is OSMfilter beginner friendly? I am having a hard time with overpass already.

Comment: osmfilter is used to take bulk files and keep only a few tags. There are plenty of examples online, also in this forum. You can use osmconvert to write csv files, which might be more user-friendly than geo-data-formats: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Writing_CSV_Files.